# LinkedIn - new invitations list

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-j, spring-social-linkedin

I want to retrieve the list of new invitations using the LinkedIn REST api. I could not find right documentation on this in their site or the "apigee". What REST url (with parameters) will list the new invitations? Do the LinkedIn provide this feature in the REST api?

Answer (score 0):

Invitation API calls are only available to LinkedIn partner developers.